# Driver for AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, ethernet, adapter

I have the following Ethernet to USB-C adapter:

```
$ lsusb | grep Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
```

When plugged into the USB-C port, it may work or not, depending on the machine. In all cases, in `dmesg` I get:

```
[23552.344134] ax88179_178a 2-1:2.1 eth1: Failed to read reg index 0x0000: -32
```

I am wondering if I have the correct driver installed. I've seen that [`axge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man4/axge.4freebsd.html) seems to be the correct driver, but it does not show up in `lsmod`.

**What is the correct driver to use for AX88179, how to check if it is installed, and how to install it otherwise?**

Comment: Mint is off-topic here.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, i am interested in knowing the answer for Ubuntu. Shouldn't the drivers for Mint be the same?

Comment: It doesn't matter: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic . And you were reminded of the exact same facts when you clicked the "Ask Question": *Questions about Pop OS, **Linux Mint**, Kali Linux, or any other distribution that is not an official flavor of Ubuntu are off-topic on this site, **and will be closed**.*

Comment: @ChanganAuto, ok, as i said, my question is not about Linux Mint. I remove the line about Mint then.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, tested with Ubuntu and Mint on another machine, updated the question to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Please run the terminal command:

```
modinfo ax88179_178a
```

If you get output, then the driver is installed on your system. It is, by default, on all recent Ubuntu versions.

Included in the output are the aliases; that is identifiers for the devices it covers. Check here:

```
alias:          usb:v0B95p1790d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

Your device, from `lsusb` is 0b95:1790, a perfect match. We know that the driver  loaded as expected since it is mentioned in `dmesg`. Moreover, you can verify that it loads with:

```
lsmod | grep ax88
```

Next, please run the terminal command:

```
modinfo axge
```

On my updated 22.04 system, it returns:

```
modinfo: ERROR: Module axge not found.
```

The driver is not installed in Ubuntu as of today. A search yields no other useful information.

> When plugged into the USB-C port, it may work or not, depending on the
> machine.

Does it not work because the driver doesn't load? Because Network Manager doesn't recognize it and connect? Because it won't connect at all, or what?

There can be many reasons that an interface doesn't work aside from the driver.

I realize that this is a partial answer until further information is given. I will supplement this answer with edits as appropriate.

Comment: I could isolate the origin the problem: [*How to fix an apparenlty missing kernel module dependency specification?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/706977).